# How to revert a View back to height of "wrap_content" after animating it to be 0dp?

Tags: android, animation, layout

I've got a TextView that I want to have an animation set on.
Initially the TextView is set to be visibility=GONE with a height of wrap_content. When the user preforms a specific action, the TextView is set to visible. After a few seconds I want to animate the height of the TextView from it's wrap_content height to 0dp. That I have working w/o any issue. My issue comes when the animation is over. After the animation is complete I set the TextView back to visibility=GONE and try to reset the TextView's height back to wrap_content but the height doens't seem to change.

I've tried setting the TextView's layout params back to height of wrap_content followed by invalidating the TextView but that doesn't work.

Any idea how to go about doing that?

Here is how I'm doing the animation currently:

```
Animation slideUp = new Animation() {
    {
        setDuration(1000);
        setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mTxtTimerSet.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                mTxtTimerSet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mTxtTimerSet.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mTxtTimerSet.invalidate();
                mTxtTimerSet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mTxtTimerSet.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = mTxtTimerSet.getHeight() - ((int) (mTxtTimerSet.getHeight() * interpolatedTime));
        mTxtTimerSet.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
};

mTxtTimerSet.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking height of your TextBox after animation finish ? Maybe you want to use `visibility=View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE` ?
 If you want to animate it again you can try to assign width when animation starts.

Comment: I've added some example code to my initial post to show exactly how I'm doing the animation. I failed to mention that was setting it to INVISIBLE before invalidating then setting it to GONE.